# sub menu item is not showing under Developer

Tags: menu

in menu under Developer, we have an arrow to go to APIv3, APTv4, and support. I just install 5.63.1, under Developer there are NO sub menu any more? any reason for that? Thanks

Comment: Should still be there, which version did you upgrade from?

Answer (score 1):

2 possible causes:

1. You are logged in as a non-administrator (those developer links are only for admins).
2. Someone has moved or deleted those menu items. To see if they still exist but got moved, try typing "api" into the search bar like this:

[image: Search the Menubar]

If they were deleted or moved, you can add them back by at the navigation menu configuration screen (**Administer -> Customize Data & Screens -> Navigation Menu**).

Comment: Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: Did you figure out the problem?